# How should I create a global options in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wpmu

I am using WPMU but there are some options that the administrator should set and should take affect for every user of the website.  Does wordpress have a place to store these global options?  Can anyone point me to sample code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first instinct would be to create my own table to store these options.  Then you have complete control over when, where, and by whom the data is accessed ... globally across all of your MU blogs.

As far as sample code goes, I'd suggest starting in the [codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Creating_Tables_with_Plugins) or trying to walk through [this tutorial](http://wptoy.com/tips-tricks/create-a-plugin-with-its-own-custom-database-table/).

Answer (score 2):

As of Wordpress 3.0 you can use add_site_option, update_site_option and get_site_option to get the option from a blog with a specific ID. So just store all admin options on one site, save that site's ID as a constant and then get all option from there.

http://codex.wordpress.org/WPMU_Functions/get_site_option